# Event and queryStringParameters are both empty, when calling a lambda function using API Gateway's Get Request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I have a lambda function invoked using an API Gateway Get Request. I filled out the query string parameter. However when I test the method, it says that both the event and query string parameter are empty objects.

```
import boto3
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print('event why no wrk:', json.dumps(event))
    print('queryStringParameters:', json.dumps(event['queryStringParameters']))
```

[image]

After looking at Cloudwatch logs, the output of the print statements are as follows:

```
2021-09-07T22:19:16.949-07:00   event why no wrk: {}

2021-09-07T22:19:16.949-07:00   [ERROR] KeyError: 'queryStringParameters' Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/var/task/
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to enable lambda integration under integration request. It binds request details in the `event` portion of the lambda handler.

[image]